# How to disable Right click inside the Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have tried most of the solutions to restrict the right click inside the iframe by doing a google search but am able to disable the right for the `<div></div>` tag but not able to restrict the right click inside the iframe window.If anybody come up with that process means share your ideas and solutions which helps me alot.This is my code

```html
<html><head>
<script type="text/JavaScript" language="JavaScript"> 
 // http://html-generator.weebly.com/html-right-click-disable-code.html 
 var tenth = ''; 
 
 function ninth() { 
   if (document.all) { 
     (tenth); 
     alert("Right Click Disable"); 
     return false; 
   } 
 } 
 
 function twelfth(e) { 
   if (document.layers || (document.getElementById && !document.all)) { 
     if (e.which == 2 || e.which == 3) { 
       (tenth); 
       return false; 
     } 
   } 
 } 
 if (document.layers) { 
   document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN); 
   document.onmousedown = twelfth; 
 } else { 
   document.onmouseup = twelfth; 
   document.oncontextmenu = ninth; 
 } 
 document.oncontextmenu = new Function('alert("Right Click Disable"); return false') 
</script></head><body>
 <div id="Container">
   <iframe id="fraDisabled"  src="http://www.stackoverflow.com" style="border: medium none;height: 820px;margin-left: -12px;top:55px; 
              margin: -15px 0 0 0;clip:rect(46px, 1360px, 750px, -65px);position:absolute;width: 1378px;">
    </iframe> 
  </div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: can we see a link or your code? what have you tried (so we dont suggest the same thing)

Comment: I have changed my post see to that @atmd

Comment: FYI all moden browsers now return Netscape as the appName

Comment: then how can i modify that script please suggest ur solution. @atmd

Comment: I started refactoring it, but there was so many issues I gave up. Sorry

Comment: Else you can try for the edited post. @atmd

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67361/discussion-between-sabari-karthik-and-atmd).

Answer (score 1):

If the iframe is in the same domain you can use [.contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) jQuery method.

```
// Grab the iframe document
var iframeEl = $('#iframeID').contents().get(0);
```

after getting the iframe element you can bind events to i:

```
// Bind event to iframe
$(iframeEl).bind('contextmenu', function(event) {
    return false;
});
```

If the iframe is in a different domain, jQuery won't allow it due to cross-domain request policy.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if the page inside an `iframe` is on the same domain. While if you access the page of a different domain inside an `iframe`, then it is not recommended.

Reference Link: [Cross Domain Policy](http://blog.cakemail.com/the-iframe-cross-domain-policy-problem/)

cheers :)