# How can i disable left-click / outgoing links on embedded videos within an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, video, youtube

I embed videos, such as from YouTube and Daily Motion on my website. I'm wondering -- is there a way to disable all outgoing links from the video itself? Perhaps I can call the video iframe's id?

I know that if it were a flash video -- I could use 
    allownetworking="internal"

I came across how to disable right click within an iFrame ([How to disable Right click inside the Iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567210/how-to-disable-right-click-inside-the-iframe)) that's on the same domain with jQuery -- perhaps I can use PHP curl to get the frame contents, iframe it and use some JS to disable left clicking/outgoing links?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. Most embedded player have a link within them which opens the video in a new tab on the host site. I would suggest using your own player if you want to stop this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I use videojs already...perhaps I can integrate 3rd party hosted videos within it.